# Aligning equations within multline

Tags: math-mode

I have this really long equation and I have used multline to break it up. I also want to align the broken bits of the equation to the left. When I use  align, for some reasons it aligns to the right when I want it to be on the left.
How can I align to the left?

```
\begin{multline}
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}_{q1} \mathcal{H}_{q2} \mathcal{H}_{q3}...\mathcal{H}_{qn}0=\frac{1}{2}H_{q1}\{\mathcal{H}_{q2}\mathcal{H}_{q3}...\mathcal{H}_{qn}0\}+\frac{1}{2} h_{q1} \\
=\frac{1}{2}H_{q1}\{\frac{1}{2} H_{q2}[\mathcal{H}_{q3}...\mathcal{H}_{qn} 0]+\frac{1}{2}h_{q2}\} +\frac{1}{2}h_{q1}=\\
\frac{1}{2}H_{q1} \frac{1}{2} H_{q2} [\frac{1}{2}H_{q3}(\mathcal{H}_{q4}..\mathcal{H}_{qn}0)+\frac{1}{2}h_{q3}]+
\frac{1}{2}h_{q2}+\frac{1}{2}h_{q1}=...\\
         =(\frac{1}{2^n})H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3}..H_{qn}0+ (\frac{1}{2^n})H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3}..H_{qn-1}h_{q1}\\+(\frac{1}{2^n})H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3}..H_{qn-2}h_{qn-1}+.. \\+
(\frac{1}{2})h_{q1}=\sum^n_{j=1} (\frac{1}{2^j}) H_{qo}H_{q1} H_{q2}H_{q3}..H_{qj-1} h_{qj}
\end{align}
\end{multline}
```

Comment: Align has nothing to do inside multline, you either use one or the other

Comment: Use align only for what you want and you can align formulas as you see fit.  Multline aligns the first line on the left, the last line on the right, and centers the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert a `multlined` environment (from `mathtools`) inside `align`. However I think it's better to use `aligned` inside align. I added a `\mathdotfill` macro with argument the length of the dotline. Also, I used the medium sized fractions fom `nccmath` fir the coefficients 1/2.

Finally, as I  wondered whether the series of  q1 ,  q2 ,  qn  and so on, is a mistyping for  q_1 ,  q_2,  q_n . So I propose this other version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\makeatother
\newcommand\EqnDots{\leaders\hbox to \linewidth{\kern4pt.\kern4pt}\hfill}
\makeatother

\newcommand\mathdotfill[1]{\makebox[#1]{$\mbox{}\kern6pt\boldsymbol \cdot \kern8pt$\xleaders\hbox{$\kern8pt\boldsymbol \cdot \kern8pt$}\hfill}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \mathcal{H}_{q1} \mathcal{H}_{q2} \mathcal{H}_{q3}\dotsm\mathcal{H}_{qn}0 & =\mfrac{1}{2}H_{q1}\{\mathcal{H}_{q2}\mathcal{H}_{q3}\dotsm\mathcal{H}_{qn}0\}+\mfrac{1}{2} h_{q1} \\ %
                    & =\mfrac{1}{2}H_{q1}\Bigl\{\mfrac{1}{2} H_{q2}[\mathcal{H}_{q3}\dotsm\mathcal{H}_{qn} 0]+\mfrac{1}{2}h_{q2}\Bigr\} +\mfrac{1}{2}h_{q1} \\ %
                    & = \mfrac{1}{2}H_{q1} \mfrac{1}{2} H_{q2}\Bigl [\mfrac{1}{2}H_{q3}(\mathcal{H}_{q4}\dotsm\mathcal{H}_{qn}0)+\mfrac{1}{2}h_{q3}\Bigr]+
  \mfrac{1}{2}h_{q2}+\mfrac{1}{2}h_{q1}\\
                    & = \mathdotfill{\eqboxwidth{M}}\notag \\
                    & = \!\begin{aligned}[t]
  \eqmakebox[M]{$ \mfrac{1}{2^n} H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3}..H_{qn}0+ \mfrac{1}{2^n} H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3}..H_{qn-1}h_{q1} $} & \\%
  {}+ \mfrac{1}{2^n} H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3}\dotsm H_{qn-2}h_{qn-1}+\dots+ \mfrac{1}{2} h_{q1} & %
  \end{aligned}\\
                    & =\sum^n_{j=1} \mfrac{1}{2^j} H_{q0}H_{q1} H_{q2}H_{q3}\dotsm H_{qj-1} h_{qj}
\end{align}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{align}
  \mathcal{H}_{q_1} \mathcal{H}_{q_2} \mathcal{H}_{q_3}\dotsm\mathcal{H}_{q_{n_0}} & =\mfrac{1}{2}H_{q_1}\{\mathcal{H}_{q_2}\mathcal{H}_{q_3}\dotsm\mathcal{H}_{q_{n_0}}\}+\mfrac{1}{2} h_{q_1} \\ %
                    & =\mfrac{1}{2}H_{q_1}\Bigl\{\mfrac{1}{2} H_{q_2}[\mathcal{H}_{q_3}\dotsm\mathcal{H}_{q_{n_0}}]+\mfrac{1}{2}h_{q_2}\Bigr\} +\mfrac{1}{2}h_{q_1} \\ %
                    & = \mfrac{1}{2}H_{q_1} \mfrac{1}{2} H_{q_2}\Bigl [\mfrac{1}{2}H_{q_3}(\mathcal{H}_{q_4}\dotsm\mathcal{H}_{q_{n_0}})+\mfrac{1}{2}h_{q_3}\Bigr]+
  \mfrac{1}{2}h_{q_2}+\mfrac{1}{2}h_{q_1}\\
                    & = \mathdotfill{\eqboxwidth{M}}\notag \\
                    & = \!\begin{aligned}[t]
  \eqmakebox[M]{$ \mfrac{1}{2^n} H_{q_1}H_{q_2}H_{q_3}\dotsm H_{q_{n_0}}+ \mfrac{1}{2^n} H_{q_1}H_{q_2}H_{q_3}..H_{q_{n-1}}h_{q_1} $} & \\%
  {}+ \mfrac{1}{2^n} H_{q_1}H_{q_2}H_{q_3}\dotsm H_{q_{n-2}}h_{q_{n-1}}+\dots+ \mfrac{1}{2} h_{q_1} & %
  \end{aligned}\\
                    & =\sum^n_{j=1} \mfrac{1}{2^j} H_{q_0}H_{q_1} H_{q_2}H_{q_3}\dotsm H_{q_{j-1}} h_{q_j}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there not an easy way to left align equations within multiline?

Comment: `multline`is not done for that. Take a look at the documentation [amsldoc.pdf](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath), p.5.

Comment: i see blank lines within the scope of `align`.  you don't want them -- they will produce error messages.

Comment: @barbara beeton: That's right, but actually there's no blank line in the code. The ‘blank lines’ have actually text that's far away in the line, due to the formatting of my editor. I'll change the layout to remove any ambiguity. Thanks!