# Why wont this equation split using \begin{align} and \end{align}

Tags: equations

I have this equation here and I am trying to split it up. 
I use the `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` commands and I use `\\` where I want the equation to split onto the next line.

Here is the code

```
\begin{align}
        \mathcal{H}_{q1} \mathcal{H}_{q2} \mathcal{H}_{q3}...\mathcal{H}_{qn}0 \\
        =\frac{1}{2}H_{q1}\{\mathcal{H}_{q2}\mathcal{H}_{q3}...\mathcal{H}_{qn}0\} \\
        +\frac{1}{2} h_{q1}\} \\
         =\frac{1}{2}H_{q1}\{\frac{1}{2} H_{q2}[\mathcal{H}_{q3}...\mathcal{H}_{qn} 0]+\frac{1}{2}h_{q2}\} +\frac{1}{2}h_{q1} \\
         =  \frac{1}{2}H_{q1} \frac{1}{2} H_{q2} \\ [\frac{1}{2}H_{q3}(\mathcal{H}_{q4}..\mathcal{H}_{qn}0)+\frac{1}{2}h_{q3}]+
         \frac{1}{2}h_{q2}+\frac{1}{2}h_{q1}.. \\
         =(\frac{1}{2^n})H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3}..H_{qn}0+   \\ (\frac{1}{2^n})H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3}..H_{qn-1}h_{q1}+(\frac{1}{2^n})H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3}..H_{qn-2}h_{qn-1}+.. +
         (\frac{1}{2})h_{q1}=\sum^n_{j=1} (\frac{1}{2^j}) H_{qo}H_{q1} H_{q2}H_{q3}..H_{qj-1} h_{qj}
        \end{align}
```

I try and compile this but nothing is outputted in place of this equation, just a blank space.

> What can I do?

Comment: Your `align` environment doesn't appear to provide any alignment points (marked by `&`).

Comment: @Mico I tried that with a few alignment points but that did not work.

Comment: "I tried that with a few alignment points" is not exactly specific, let alone actionable. Please show us what you did try. For sure, if you provide no alignment points, there's little point in using an `align` environment.

Comment: It's more or less the [same equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319675/aligning-equations-within-multline) you posted a week ago, for which there's an answer which supposedly solved the problem.

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks for pointing out that this is basically a duplicate of an earlier posting; in consequence, I've closed the posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some guessing how your equation should looks, I obtain:

[image]

MWE for above picture is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
\mathcal{H}_{q1} 
    &   \mathcal{H}_{q2} \mathcal{H}_{q3} \dots \mathcal{H}_{qn}0   \notag  \\
    & =\frac{1}{2}H_{q1}\{\mathcal{H}_{q2}\mathcal{H}_{q3} \dots \mathcal{H}_{qn}0\}
        +\frac{1}{2} h_{q1}\} \\
    & =\frac{1}{2}H_{q1}\{\frac{1}{2} H_{q2}[\mathcal{H}_{q3} \dots \mathcal{H}_{qn} 0] + \frac{1}{2}h_{q2}\} +\frac{1}{2}h_{q1} \\
    & =  \frac{1}{2}H_{q1} \frac{1}{2} H_{q2} [\frac{1}{2}H_{q3}(\mathcal{H}_{q4} \dots \mathcal{H}_{qn}0)+\frac{1}{2}h_{q3}]+
         \frac{1}{2}h_{q2}+\frac{1}{2}h_{q1} \dots \\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t][0.7\textwidth]
        (\frac{1}{2^n})H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3} \dots H_{qn}0+
        (\frac{1}{2^n})H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3} \dots H_{qn-1}h_{q1}+ \\
        (\frac{1}{2^n})H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3} \dots H_{qn-2}h_{qn-1}+ \dots +
        (\frac{1}{2})h_{q1} 
        \end{multlined}                \\
    & = \sum^n_{j=1} (\frac{1}{2^j}) H_{qo}H_{q1} H_{q2}H_{q3} \dots H_{qj-1} h_{qj}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Hopefully this can serve as star to format your equations. Otherwise they contain many surplus parenthesis, some are not adopted to heights of expression in them etc.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided any alignment points, so I've had to make a few educated guesses as to where you want them to be. Maybe something like the following is what you're after? If I've mis-guessed, please do clarify what you're after.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'align' environment
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set text block parameters
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}_{q1} \mathcal{H}_{q2} \mathcal{H}_{q3}
   \dotsm\mathcal{H}_{qn}0 
&=\tfrac{1}{2}H_{q1}\{\mathcal{H}_{q2}\mathcal{H}_{q3}
   \dotsm\mathcal{H}_{qn}0\} +\tfrac{1}{2} h_{q1} \\
&=\tfrac{1}{2}H_{q1}\bigl\{\tfrac{1}{2} H_{q2}[\mathcal{H}_{q3}
   \dotsm\mathcal{H}_{qn} 0]+\tfrac{1}{2}h_{q2}\bigr\} 
   +\tfrac{1}{2}h_{q1} \\
&=\tfrac{1}{2}H_{q1} \tfrac{1}{2} H_{q2} 
   \bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}H_{q3}(\mathcal{H}_{q4}
   \dotsm\mathcal{H}_{qn}0)+\tfrac{1}{2}h_{q3}\bigr]+
   \tfrac{1}{2}h_{q2}+\tfrac{1}{2}h_{q1}+\dotsb   \\
&=\tfrac{1}{2^n}H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3}
   \dotsm H_{qn}0 +\tfrac{1}{2^n}H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3}
   \dotsm H_{qn-1}h_{q1}\\
&\qquad +\tfrac{1}{2^n}H_{q1}H_{q2}H_{q3}
   \dotsm H_{qn-2}h_{qn-1}+\dotsb+\tfrac{1}{2}h_{q1}\\
&=\sum^n_{j=1} \tfrac{1}{2^j} H_{qo}H_{q1} H_{q2}H_{q3}
   \dotsm H_{qj-1} h_{qj}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```